# Large coefficients in DiD

Tags: regression-coefficients, multicollinearity, difference-in-difference

I am examining whether a regulatory change affects profit margins (PM) and return on assets (ROA) using a difference-in-difference test.
Firms are divided into treatment (T=1) and non-treatment (T=0). The variable POST=0 before the adoption of the policy and POST=1 after the adoption.

Fixed effects used: Country-year, industry-year, firm
Standard errors are clustered on a firm-level

The problem is that my coefficients are very large in relation to the standard deviation. This is especially true for the non-DID estimators (T and POST). The coefficients are 2-3x larger than the standard deviation. 
Is this something that I need to worry about? Is it problematic that they are also statistically significant at the 1%-level?

Comment: Carefully define the baseline in this case. Consider using *firm* as a random effect. Plot your data and do some EDA - do large differences appear plausible? Consider reformulating your mode as a quantile regression model - maybe there is only a handful of firms that made huge gains post-policy but actually the vast majority of firms saw little to no changes. Bootstrap this.

Comment: Many thanks for providing me with a solution to this. If I do not manage to solve this, is this a large problem?

Comment: These are suggestions, not answers; but I am glad you find the constructive. :) In the end of the day, we decide on a model (a series of assumptions) and run with it. If the results are implausible we get back to the drawing board! Large (or any magnitude of) coefficients are not a problem they are just what they are. By the way, make sure variables are in informative scales and/or standardised appropriately!

Comment: I fail to see why using random effects at the firm level makes sense, firm are different but this is seldom random, fixed effects are for this kind of thing. Using quantile regression methods are likely to complicate things a lot, for example you cannot estimate the average treatment effect, you will likely need more data, and you are going to make more (and stronger) assumptions. I do however think it's very useful to see what happens if the most effective firms are excluded from the analysis. Note that changing the scales can be helpful in interpretation, but it will not change the inference

Comment: Perhaps I should add that there is no rule saying that standard errors cannot be very small relative to its coefficient. Indeed it is very common, mechanically it implies that there is much variation in the variables, and so multicollinearity is likely a non issue for you.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply Repmat! Is there a systematic and legitimate way to reduce these firms so it does not appear that I have manipulated the data?

Comment: @Repmat: Why do you think that DiD will suffer from quantile regression? Sure we will change our interpretation to "median" or against a particular quantile instead of mean but that's not necessarily a problem for DiD.(I am asking out of interest, nothing confrontational!) (And yes, firm probably are better as a fixed effect given how many replicates we have, I most mentioned it as a conceptual issue as it is not in the researcher control and/or exclusively sampled.)

Comment: @usεr11852, I am sorry if my comment came off as confrontational - that was not my intention. Quantile regression and fixed effects, are a lot more diffucelt to combine than most people think. You cannot simply define the groups as in DiD for the mean, apply (say) median regression (LAD), and interpret as a treatment effect at the median. The short version (of the very technical reasons why this does not work) is that the quantile of the difference is not the difference of the quantiles - unlike for the mean. To be clear you can apply quantile regression, but it requires stronger assumptions.

Comment: @Repmat: Thank you; I will take that on board. Having said that - yes, the quantile of the difference is not the difference of the quantiles but actually we don't ask for the "difference of the quantiles" we ask for the "quantile of the difference".